# Creating a web server proxy for static website in Azure

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I have a static website in Azure that's hosted using the **blob storage account**. I need to make requests from this website to services hosted in other domains. In order to handle CORS, I need to build a forward proxy server that handles the requests from client and forwards them to the requested service. Similarly, response from the services will be forwarded to the client. What is the recommended way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an Azure Function (with consumption plan) using your favourite programming language. Just send requests from front end to the Azure Function, then once you get the reply from 3rd party servers, return it to the front end.

PS: use the Http Trigger binding

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook?tabs=csharp